# Matlab text overflows legend

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure, legend-properties

Very irritating there is enough size on the graph to widen the legend but it does not resize automatically to the content. Anyone a suggestion on how  to fix this? (latex interpreter set to legend)

Error marked in red where legend data falls out of the legend box

[image]

[image]

Fully minimal working example of my problem:

```
window=figure('Visible','on');
axes1 = axes('Parent',window);
grid(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');
set(window, 'Position', [0 0 1000 1000]);

x=rand(1000,1);
y=rand(1000,1);
companyMap='companyname of datapoint'

%draw scatter in window
scatter(x,y,'fill','MarkerFaceColor',[0,0,1],'MarkerEdgeColor',[0,0,1],'Marker','.','SizeData',30,'Parent',axes1,'DisplayName',sprintf('%s Datapoint',strrep(companyMap,'&','\&')));
linFit = fitlm(x,y);
dispName = sprintf('Linear fit: $y=%.3f x+ %.3f$, $R^{2}=%.3f$',linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(2),linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(1),linFit.Rsquared.Ordinary);
if linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(1) < 0
    dispName = strrep(dispName,'+','');
end
%lsline('linewidth',2,'Parent',axes1,'DisplayName',dispName);
line(x,linFit.Fitted,'Parent',axes1,'Tag','lsline','Color',[0 0 0],'DisplayName',dispName,'linewidth',2);
legend1 = legend(axes1,'show');
set(legend1,'Interpreter','latex');
%set(legend1, 'FontSize',7);
set(legend1,'Location','Best');

% Create title
title( { 'tit' }, 'FontSize',20);
% Create xlabel
xlabel( { 'x' } , 'FontSize',16, 'Interpreter','LaTex');
% Create ylabel
ylabel( { 'y' } , 'FontSize',16, 'Interpreter','LaTex');
```

Comment: As you haven't provided any code to help us guessing what is wrong, I assume you actually used pen an paper. I'd recommend to use a rubber, remove the overflown line by rubbing, and draw a new one.

Comment: ah, I forgot: **;)** -> no offense

Comment: Can you post just the relevant part of the code? And the code should be runnable. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I fully understand you but I thought my first question was enough for some reason... It costs a little time to obfuscate code, I was just being lazy like a programmer should be (in most cases) :P @Luis, one moment

Comment: Added requested files, please undo downvotes :(

Comment: using 'best' as placement does not work for every figure and changing FontSize also does not give the wanted result

Comment: For me your code works as it is supposed to do.

Comment: I am using Matlab R2014a on windows 8.1 . If you use the same I would like proof of your claim because for me it does not work.

Comment: Break the line with `'\n'` in `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks Yvon but unfortunately not a very good solution since in some graphs, the formula itself overflows the legend box' right side...

Comment: `[hleg1, hobj1] = legend(axes1,'show'); textobj = findobj(hobj1, 'type', 'text'); set(textobj, 'Interpreter', 'latex'); set(hleg1,'position',[.2,.2,.8,.8])`http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63519-how-can-i-enlarge-the-legend-box-size

Comment: thanks adding this worked set(legend1,'position',[0.5 0.8 0.4 0.1]) while removing set(legend1,'Location','Best');

Comment: @BigChief - Please add the solution that worked for you as an answer and accept it so that this question appears resolved (like it really is).

Comment: anyway, you wanted a "proof": [click me!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmkb2f5nuznf7ry/Capture.PNG) Thats what gives your code just with copy and paste out of the box on my machine. Windows 8.1 and Matlab 2014a. So I'd say you screwed something up with some settings, would be interesting to know if a restart of matlab helped?

Comment: looks like you cheated and changed the font size, anyway i'll change it to resolved

Answer (score 0):

Working example with solution set(legend1,'position',[0.5 0.8 0.4 0.1])

```
window=figure('Visible','on');
axes1 = axes('Parent',window);
grid(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');
set(window, 'Position', [0 0 1000 1000]);

x=rand(1000,1);
y=rand(1000,1);
companyMap='companyname of datapoint'

%draw scatter in window
scatter(x,y,'fill','MarkerFaceColor',[0,0,1],'MarkerEdgeColor',[0,0,1],'Marker','.','SizeData',30,'Parent',axes1,'DisplayName',sprintf('%s Datapoint',strrep(companyMap,'&','\&')));
linFit = fitlm(x,y);
dispName = sprintf('Linear fit: $y=%.3f x+ %.3f$, $R^{2}=%.3f$',linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(2),linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(1),linFit.Rsquared.Ordinary);
if linFit.Coefficients.Estimate(1) < 0
    dispName = strrep(dispName,'+','');
end
%lsline('linewidth',2,'Parent',axes1,'DisplayName',dispName);
line(x,linFit.Fitted,'Parent',axes1,'Tag','lsline','Color',[0 0 0],'DisplayName',dispName,'linewidth',2);
legend1 = legend(axes1,'show');
set(legend1,'Interpreter','latex');
%set(legend1, 'FontSize',7);
set(legend1,'position',[0.5 0.8 0.4 0.1])

% Create title
title( { 'tit' }, 'FontSize',20);
% Create xlabel
xlabel( { 'x' } , 'FontSize',16, 'Interpreter','LaTex');
% Create ylabel
ylabel( { 'y' } , 'FontSize',16, 'Interpreter','LaTex');
```